# How to hot reload a development package in an Expo app example nested folder?

Tags: react-native, expo, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, npm-package

Is it possible to an Expo app example to load a module located in the parent folder AND to see changes in the example app when i rebuild the package (with tsc -w to rebuild on any saved files)?
I precise that the module is not publish on npm yet.

I've already succeed to do that using monorepo architecture with yarn workspaces and expo-yarn-workspaces package.
But what about the case when you don't want to publish your package like a monorepo?

For example, in this repo https://github.com/cuvent/react-native-vision-camera
There is an example RN app in bare workflow and in its package.json there is no mention of the developed package (meaning that it's not installed like a normal dependency).
But in the app src/App.tsx, the package is used like that :

```
import { Camera, frameRateIncluded, sortFormatsByResolution, filterFormatsByAspectRatio } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
```

Though, the react-native-vision-camera is used like it's already and normally installed with yarn or npm.
How does it work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found something that works for me.
You can find my config for metro if you want here:
https://github.com/grean/react-native-metro-config-app-example
With it, you can access the parent component from the expo app, modify it and immediately see the hot-reload changes.
Create a file metro.config file in your expo root app directory with that code inside:

```js
let config = require('@grean/react-native-metro-config-app-example/index.js');
module.exports = config
```

For a whole example, you can check this repo out:
https://github.com/grean/react-native-scale-text